# asp.net scheduler for appointments

Tags: asp.net

I want a appointment scheduler which consists of four time slots in 1 hour and clicking each slot, a popup externder opens so that we can add appointments in that specific slot and there will be written 'Booked' on other three.
Can anybody helps me.
Thanx in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you encounter some particular problems with your code?

Comment: Is this just a duplicate of your other post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693958/canlender-for-appointments-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

You best bet is to use the Telerik Scheduler. It should allow you with a little configuration to do exactly what you're after.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx